# Change date format on Google forms responses automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I currently have my form responses coming into a google sheet and currently the date format is 10/01/2020 but I ideally want it in this format - "Friday 10 Jan" so I have been selecting the column and change the format. However, when a new form is submitted, it continues to come in as 10/01/2020. I have looked at using the Utilities.formatDate function in the apps script however I am very new to this!

The date is currently going into column C.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using Google Apps Script to change the formatting of your date column into your desired format.

### One approach:

1. Create a script linked to your sheet: Open your responses spreadsheet, go to -> Menu/Tools/Script Editor
2. Use the [`onOpen(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) simple trigger function to execute a format-changing instruction when you open the sheet.

### Example:

```js
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  // Gets the response sheet
  var date_column = ss.getRange('B:B');      // Gets the date column
  date_column.setNumberFormat('dddd-dd-mmm'); // Change to your format  
}
```

### Further reading:

[Date and number formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats)